# how to use GROUP BY twice with MySQL squery

Tags: mysql, sql

My table **current_data** looks like this.

```
GSM_ID      UploadTime                comment_id    U03
330010      2022-10-05 07:00:00       3255          15.5
330011      2022-10-05 07:15:00       3245          142.2
330010      2022-10-05 07:30:00       3258          122
330011      2022-10-05 07:45:00       3235          144
330010      2022-10-05 08:00:00       3253          12
330011      2022-10-05 08:15:00       3257          147.2
330010      2022-10-05 08:30:00       3243          15.20
330011      2022-10-05 08:45:00       3251          16.3
```

device_info is other table which contain the names of devices by gsm_id.
i managed to get data grouped by 15 min with this query :

```
    SELECT 
        `current_data`.`GSM_ID` AS `ID`,
        `device_info`.`GSM_NAME` AS `Site`,
        ('1000-01-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL (CEILING((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,
                    '1000-01-01 00:00:00',
                    `current_data`.`UploadTime`) / 15)) * 15) MINUTE) AS `Jour`,
        MIN(IF((ISNULL(`current_data`.`U03`)
                OR (`current_data`.`U03` = '')),
            0,
            `current_data`.`U03`)) AS `IndexDebut`,
        MAX(IF((ISNULL(`current_data`.`U03`)
                OR (`current_data`.`U03` = '')),
            0,
            `current_data`.`U03`)) AS `IndexFin`
        AVG(`current_data`.`U03`) AS `U03`
        FROM
        (`current_data`
        JOIN `current_data` ON ((`current_data`.`GSM_ID` = `current_data`.`GSM_ID`)))
    WHERE
        ((`current_data`.`GSM_ID` = '330010')
            OR (`current_data`.`GSM_ID` = '330011'))
    GROUP BY ('1000-01-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL (CEILING((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,
                '1000-01-01 00:00:00',
                `current_data`.`UploadTime`) / 15)) * 15) MINUTE) , `device_info`.`GSM_NAME`
    ORDER BY `current_data`.`UploadTime` DESC 



    GSM_ID   Site     Jour                      IndexDebut     IndexFin   U03
    330010   hcd      2022-10-05 07:00:00       15.5           15.5       15.5
    330011   vfc      2022-10-05 07:15:00       142.2          142.2      142.2
    330010   hcd      2022-10-05 07:30:00       122            122        122
    330011   vfc      2022-10-05 07:45:00       144            144        144
    330010   hcd      2022-10-05 08:00:00       12             12         12
    330011   vfc      2022-10-05 08:15:00       147.2          147.2      147.2
    330010   hcd      2022-10-05 08:30:00       15.20          15.20      15.20
    330011   vfc      2022-10-05 08:45:00       16.3           16.3       16.3
```

what i want is getting the max of U03 in *IndexFin* and the min in *IndexDebut* within 24hour
so tha table will bacome like this :

```
    GSM_ID   Site     Jour                      IndexDebut     IndexFin    U03
    330010   hcd      2022-10-05 07:00:00       12             147.2       15.5
    330011   vfc      2022-10-05 07:15:00       12             147.2       142.2
    330010   hcd      2022-10-05 07:30:00       12             147.2       122
    330011   vfc      2022-10-05 07:45:00       12             147.2       144
    330010   hcd      2022-10-05 08:00:00       12             147.2       12
    330011   vfc      2022-10-05 08:15:00       12             147.2       147.2
    330010   hcd      2022-10-05 08:30:00       12             147.2       15.20
    330011   vfc      2022-10-05 08:45:00       12             147.2       16.3
```

i need to do another GROUP BY with Date so how ?
pls help!

Comment: your query will produce an error as you have the same tbale twice, also you have in your query  `device_info`  that is nowhere defined

Comment: device_info is other table which contain the names of devices by gsm_id as i mentioned

Comment: You can't use GROUP BY twice. You *can* add additional columns in your existing GROUP BY clause. Separate them with a comma.

Comment: @KenWhite how can i do it while im grouping the first select ?

Comment: Please put it all in a dbfiddle and post a link here.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  GSM_ID
       ,site
       ,Jour
       ,min(IndexDebut) over(partition by date(Jour)) as IndexDebut
       ,max(IndexFin) over(partition by date(Jour))   as IndexFin
       ,U03
from    t join t2 using(GSM_ID, U03)
```

| GSM_ID | site | Jour | IndexDebut | IndexFin | U03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 330010 | hcd | 2022-10-05 07:00:00 | 12.00 | 147.20 | 15.50 |
| 330011 | vfc | 2022-10-05 07:15:00 | 12.00 | 147.20 | 142.20 |
| 330010 | hcd | 2022-10-05 07:30:00 | 12.00 | 147.20 | 122.00 |
| 330011 | vfc | 2022-10-05 07:45:00 | 12.00 | 147.20 | 144.00 |
| 330010 | hcd | 2022-10-05 08:00:00 | 12.00 | 147.20 | 12.00 |
| 330011 | vfc | 2022-10-05 08:15:00 | 12.00 | 147.20 | 147.20 |
| 330010 | hcd | 2022-10-05 08:30:00 | 12.00 | 147.20 | 15.20 |
| 330011 | vfc | 2022-10-05 08:45:00 | 12.00 | 147.20 | 16.30 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1IiS7HMs)